# @ViewChild('slidePrincipal') slides: IonSlides; no funciona Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

estoy tratando de bloquear el slde de mi aplicacion de ionic pero el `@ViewChild('slidePrincipal')` me genera un error `Expected 2 arguments, but got 1` por lo que lo puse de esta forma `@ViewChild('slidePrincipal',{ read: true, static: false })`

Al final el codigo debe quedar mas o menos asi
`@ViewChild('slidePrincipal',{ read: true, static: false }) slides: IonSlides;`

pero cuando imprimo en consola mi variable slides me sale `undefined`
`console.log(this.slides);`

la cabecera de mi ion-slide:
`<ion-slides class="mainSlide" #slidePrincipal id="slidePrincipal">`

Alguna ayuda de porque esto no me esta funcionando?

Answer (score 0):

me ocurría lo mismo y era porque debía establecer static a true. ¿Has probado a establecer 'static: true'?

```
@ViewChild('slidePrincipal',{ read: true, static: true }) slides: IonSlides;
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Perfecto, edito.